# Does Rsnapshot work on Fat32 filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, rsnapshot, fat32

Does Rsnapshot work on the Fat32 filesystem?

I get the impression from Rsnapshots [homepage](http://www.rsnapshot.org/) that it does, but then I read [here](http://www.openfsg.com/index.php/Install_and_setup_rsnapshot_to_make_automated_backups) that it doesn't.

So I'm not sure what to think.

Comment: 1) What about just trying it out (e.g. in a VM) 2) Fat32 is a terrible FS choice for a backup. Even if it would work in some cases, I wouldn't do it.

Comment: Which filesystem would you use for a backup?

Comment: I use ZFS and ext3. But there are plenty of others which will do a great job, too. Go for an FS with unix permission support.

Comment: Do those work with Rsync and Rsnapshot?

Comment: And do they work on a Mac?

Comment: Both work with rsync and rsnapshot without problems. But I have no clue about macs.

Answer (score 5):

In general `rsnapshot` is just making use of `rsync` so it should work fine with backing up a variety of files from file systems such as ext3, ext4, FAT, and NTFS.

The comment that you're referring to:

> Backing up to external usb HDD's works perfectly, but one needs to use
>   a ext3 or similar formatted drive that supports hard links. So no
>   FAT32 or NTFS drives.

Is only saying that you have to use a file system such as ext3 or ext4 as the file system that you're backing up to.

This comment has to do with the mechanism that `rsnapshot` enlists to make it's backups. `Rsnapshot` similar to another tool, [`rdiff-backup`](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/), is saving disk space by creating links to files within a given backup vs. actually making a physical copy of the same file day in and day out.

#### For example

Say we have this directory being backed up:

```
$ tree somedir
somedir
|-- afile1
|-- afile2
|-- afile3
`-- afile4
```

**Day1's** backup would include all the contents of *somedir*.

Now let's say we only changed file afile4 during **Day1**, so in **Day2's** backup, we'd have links to files *afile1* - *afile3* and a new copy of *afile4*.

Rsnapshot is creating links in the file system from backup set to backup set for files/directories that haven't changed from the prior day.

In order to make these links, you need to have a file system that supports feature, which the FAT/FAT32 file systems common on a lot of external USB drives, doesn't.